# google script: File class is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make my google docs script create a backup copy of the file each time I open it.
To make a copy I write

```
var name = File.getName();
var filecopy = File.makeCopy(name + " backup");
```

But it won't recognize the File class. Although it knows DocsList. How do I make it work or make a copy of the file another way?

Answer (score 1):

GAS permits to call class methods or instance only native classes (`Object`, `String`, etc), own classes or Google Services (`DocList`, `SpreadsheetApp`, etc). Other classes like `File`, `Folder`, `Spreadsheet`, `Range`, etc are accessible and instanceable only via calling the services functions, for example, `DocsList.getFileById("...");` returns the `File` class instance.

The following function copies a file having the `srcFileID` ID to a new file with the name stored in the `dstFileName` parameter.

```
function testCopy(srcFileID, dstFileName) {
  var srcFile = DocsList.getFileById(srcFileID);
  srcFile.makeCopy(dstFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the File class that way. Use something on these lines

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById(ID) ; // you can use DocsList.find or DocsList.create 
var filecopy = file.makeCopy();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! and how do I know my file's ID (spreadsheet)?

Comment: You can use the find() function as I mentioned in the comment or you can get the ID from the browser's address bar (the part following key= and before #gid=)